# Laravel named route to directory

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Is there possible way to make named route in laravel for directory? For example I have directory named **stats** in **public** directory, and I wanna to be able to call it as route('page.stats').

Comment: Why do you want to use from 'public' folder? You want use it as view or something else?

Comment: @EmreDoğan well Im using 3rd party software what I can't integrate into laravel and I wan't to make named route for that folder so laravel knows what link to return when Im using something like route('page.stats')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is not frameworklike. In this case I suggest you to move out the resorce (probably index.php) from public to somewhere else and then call it from the controller.

If you still want to run it under this path, here is a solvation. In the routing file add:

```
Route::get('page/stats', function () {
    return require public_path('stats/index.php');
});
```

Comment: Im using 3rd party software what I can't integrate into laravel so I need to make named route like page.stats for this **stats** folder into **public** directory because I need laravel to know what url return when I use smth like this route('page.stats')

Comment: As I show you above - you can place this 3rd party wherever you want. You just need to define it in routing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move out this files from `public` folder and under `app` folder you can create a `Helper` folder and move them to there and you have to declare path to this `Helper` folder if you are using 3rd party softwares as classes. In `composer.json` file under `autoload` array you can declare classes or files. If you are using 3rd party softwares as a single file and want to use them every request you can add as a `file` and include easily.

My `composer.json` file structure is like that :

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files" : [
        "app/Helpers.php",
        "app/Helpers/company-helpers.php"
    ]
}
```

I think you should use like this otherwise using 3rd party softwares under `public` folder is not good thing fot using in MVC design pattern.